# Debug CMake find_library

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to debug `find_library` from CMake?

What I want is a list of considered paths. My use case is a call like

```
find_library (FOO_LIBRARY
              NAMES foo foo.so.0)
```

and there is `/lib64/libfoo.so.0` on my system. However CMake does not find it. I checked that `FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS` is set to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With CMake 3.17 this [got added](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-3-17-0-available-for-download/):

> The “CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE” variable was introduced to print extra
> find call information during the cmake run to standard error. Output
> is designed for human consumption and not for parsing.

So you pass either `-DCMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON` or `--debug-find` to your CMake command.

Here is an example output when searching for libFOO:

```
find_library considered the following locations:

/usr/local/lib64/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/usr/local/lib/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/usr/local/lib64/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/usr/local/lib/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/usr/local/lib64/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/usr/local/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/usr/lib64/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/usr/lib/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/usr/lib64/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/usr/lib/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/usr/lib64/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/usr/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/lib64/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/lib/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)
/opt/(lib)FOO(\.so|\.a)

The item was not found.
```

Comment: This seems to work for find_package, but not find_library for me (cmake v3)

Comment: @ndtreviv There no such thing as CMake v3. Do you mean 3.0? The number after the dot is important. My answer explicitly states CMake >= 3.17.

Answer (score 4):

I know this isn't a complete answer, but I had the same problem and found that it was necessary to add debug logging to find_library in the CMake source code. I submitted a [pull request](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/2313) (work in progress) to add this to mainstream CMake.

I eliminated some possible sources of errors by logging an error message with some relevant details if `find_library` fails, like this:

```
    set(libssl_names
            ssl${_OPENSSL_MSVC_ARCH_SUFFIX}${_OPENSSL_MSVC_RT_MODE}
            ssl${_OPENSSL_MSVC_RT_MODE}
            ssl
            ssleay32${_OPENSSL_MSVC_RT_MODE}
            ssleay32
    )

    find_library(SSL_EAY_DEBUG
            NAMES ${libssl_names}
            NAMES_PER_DIR
            PATHS ${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}
            PATH_SUFFIXES ${_OPENSSL_PATH_SUFFIXES}
            NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    )

    if(NOT SSL_EAY_DEBUG)
            message(FATAL_ERROR "OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR is set to '${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}', but did not find any file matching ${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}/{${_OPENSSL_PATH_SUFFIXES}}/${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES}{${libssl_names}}${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES}")
    endif()
```

Which outputs something like:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:526 (message):
  OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR is set to '../../Install/openssl/', but did not find any
  file matching
  ../../Install/openssl//{lib/VC/static;VC/static;lib}/lib{ssl64MT;sslMT;ssl;ssleay32MT;ssleay32}.a
```

Apart from semicolons (instead of commas) in the {braced} portions of the above pattern, and regexes if multiple CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES are configured (e.g. `.lib .a` on Windows), this is the correct form for shell expansion to a list of paths, which you can pass to `ls` to check for their existence:

```
$ ls ../../Install/openssl//{lib/VC/static,VC/static,lib}/lib{ssl64MT,sslMT,ssl,ssleay32MT,ssleay32}.a
ls: ../../Install/openssl//VC/static/libssl.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//VC/static/libssl64MT.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//VC/static/libsslMT.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//VC/static/libssleay32.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//VC/static/libssleay32MT.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//lib/VC/static/libssl.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//lib/VC/static/libssl64MT.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//lib/VC/static/libsslMT.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//lib/VC/static/libssleay32.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//lib/VC/static/libssleay32MT.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//lib/libssl64MT.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//lib/libsslMT.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//lib/libssleay32.a: No such file or directory
ls: ../../Install/openssl//lib/libssleay32MT.a: No such file or directory
../../Install/openssl//lib/libssl.a
```

It's not obvious (at least to me) that:

- relative paths (like `../../Install` above) are actually relative to the original source directory (not the current project build directory, which CMake calls [CMAKE_BINARY_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html). (So you should run `ls` from there, not your build directory).
- [FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_gbl/FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS.html), which is often ON by default, results in your original paths being replaced by mangled ones (lib -> lib64) (not just supplemented by additional search paths, but completely replaced).
- Other, even less well-known properties such as FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB32_PATHS result in similar mangling (lib -> lib32).
- This mangling can be disabled with `set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_CUSTOM_LIB_SUFFIX "")`.